# Is it possible to replace file input data with my own image's data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-processing

I'd like to know how I can replace `<input type="file">`'s file clicking on a button that'll update it with a `data:image/...;base64` type data. I'd like to do this because the server will take whatever is inside the `input` and not on my image.

**HTML**

```
<input id="fileimage" type="file">
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
   var image = document.getElementById("image").src;
   // from 'image' to 'fileimage' (image is under 'data:image/...;base64' type format)
};
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to overwrite file input `base64` data, the only thing you can do with it is to erase whatever is inside. What I did instead is that I saved `base64` data inside a hidden input and decoded it into a file again on the server side.